# Custom UIView form

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am just wondering how to make a custom form for UIView. To be more exact, take a look at Messages - all messages' forms are rounded, but from either left or right side there is a little pointer/hook (showing the source side of a message). So that's what I want to know in case of its implementation. How does it work? I though it could be the second translucent view layered right onto the initial one, but who knows that is being under the hood. Thank you in advance!

P.S. A little example in the photograph below. (Pay an attention to the black option panel and its hook on the bottom.)

[image]

Comment: This is a really broad question.

Comment: Definitely, you're right about it. I have read that in most cases either Quartz or OpenGL libraries are used to achieve those effects. But in any way I'd like to know how it works. Any recommended resource is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Well, there are tons of ways to do this. The first that comes to my mind is using a masking layer. Check out `CALayer`'s `mask` property.